# IOS - set viewcontroller equal to rootviewcontroller (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, dynamic-library

I'm making a framework for an iOS app, I'm trying to add views directly to the rootviewcontroller.
For this I first retrieve the rootviewcontroller with:

```
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
rootvc = window.rootViewController;
```

Now I have a class which is a subclass of a `UIViewcontroller` like this:

`@implementation mainView : UIViewController`

What I am trying to achieve is assign the rootviewcontroller to the viewcontroller so I can use `[self addSubview:example]`

What I already tried and didn't work:

```
[self presentViewcontroller:rootvc animated:YES completion:nil];
self = rootvc
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not a very good description. Can you please go more into detail?

Comment: [self presentViewcontroller:rootvc animated:YES completion:nil];
this works but nothing shows up on the app

Comment: self = rootvc
this gives an Xcode error: cannot assign self outside of a method in the init family

Comment: what you want to achieve? I am not clear with your question exactly!

Comment: I am making a framework for an iOS app, I have retrieved the rootviewcontroller of this app but I want to control it via a subclass of a uiviewcontroller.